# В чем заключается ошибка вывода списка?

Tags: python-3.x

Выдает ошибку при запуске кода:

```
cars = ['bmw', 'toyota', 'honda']
print("\n" + cars)
```

А именно:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print("\n" + cars)
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Но если так:

```
cars = ['bmw', 'toyota', 'honda']
print("\n" + str(cars))
```

То ошибки нет, ПОЧЕМУ?

Comment: потому что строку с массивом складывать нельзя. А строку со строкой можно. Функция str() делает из объекта (массива) строку https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/str

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в том, что в Python строку со списком складывать нельзя

Вы можете либо **конкатенировать-объединить(сложить) списки**, либо **конкатенировать-объединить(сложить) строки**.

`listnumone = [1,2,3]
 listnumtwo = [4,5,6]
 mergedlist = listnumone + listnumtwo`

Либо

`str1="Первая часть+"
 str2="Вторая часть."
 mergestr=str1+str2`